# How to run MSBuild.exe as admin from the command line in GitHub pipeline?

Tags: c#, github, cmd, msbuild

I'm using a simple step in Github pipeline to build a project:

```
- name: Build Solution
    run: |
      msbuild.exe ${{ env.PROJ_PATH }} /p:Configuration=Release
```

I need this command to run in elevated mode.
(e.g If I'd copile this project manually, I'd open Visual Studio as administrator.)

**How can I do it in the command?**

Thank You!